# Gali - Monetary Policy - Solutions?

Tags: monetary-policy

I am working through exercises in Gali but some of them are rather difficult. I am trying to find a solutions manual to use as an aide for exercises that completely stump me and to confirm solutions for the exercises I have completed.

Does anyone here know if Gali or some other economists published solutions for his exercises?  I have searched extensively with no luck but it seems like there must be some sort of solutions manual available for this text. It is widely used. 
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe that a solution manual to Gali's book has been written. In 2015 the book [saw a second edition](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/10495.html), so maybe this time around something will appear.
These [course notes](http://bergholt.weebly.com/uploads/1/1/8/4/11843961/the_basic_new_keynesian_model_-_drago_bergholt.pdf) may be indirectly helpful to you.

Comment: This was actually very useful for confirming my way through his layout of the N.K. model. Thanks for this. It doesn't help with confirming my answers to his exercises but it was very useful.

Comment: @guestguestguest  That's good to hear.